# rearrange primer3 boulder IO output

Tags: text-processing, scripting, bioinformatics

I'm trying to rearrange `primer3_core` output.

For example:

```
SEQUENCE_ID=ID_1
PRIMER_LEFT_0_SEQUENCE=ACGTGTAGCGGTTCAGACG
PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SEQUENCE=ACCATGCATGATCCATCCAGG
PRIMER_LEFT_1_SEQUENCE=CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SEQUENCE=ATGCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCC
=
SEQUENCE_ID=ID_2
PRIMER_LEFT_0_SEQUENCE=CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SEQUENCE=GCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCCATT
=
```

So, it's possible that each ID would have a different number of primers it produces, anywhere from 0-20.

The output would look like this:

```
ID_1 ACGTGTAGCGGTTCAGACG
ID_1 ACCATGCATGATCCATCCAGG
ID_1 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_1 ATGCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCC
ID_2 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_2 GCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCCATT
```

Comment: By the way, we also have a dedicated [Bioinformatics.se] site. Come check it out!

Comment: If you're happy with one or several of the answers, upvote them.  If one is solving your issue, [accepting it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) would be the best way of saying "Thank You!" :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F= '$0 ~ "^SEQUENCE" {SEQ=$2} $0 !~ "^SEQUENCE" { print SEQ" "$2 }' filename
```

Use awk and use = as the field delimiter. Where then line begins with SEQUENCE, set the SEQ variable equal to the second delimited piece. For all other instances, print SEQ along with the second delimited piece of data

Answer (score 1):

**Awk** approach:

```
awk -F'=' '/^SEQUENCE_ID/{ s = $2 }/^PRIMER/{ print s, $2 }' file
```

The output:

```
ID_1 ACGTGTAGCGGTTCAGACG
ID_1 ACCATGCATGATCCATCCAGG
ID_1 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_1 ATGCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCC
ID_2 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_2 GCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCCATT
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a `sed` script:

```
# delete lines starting with '='
/^=/d

# handle sequence ID lines
/^SEQUENCE_ID=/{
    # remove everything up to and including the '='
    s///
    # put the sequence ID in the hold space
    h
    # delete the pattern space and continue with next line
    d
}

# handle primer lines
/^PRIMER.*=/{
    # remove everything up to and including the '='
    s///
    # append a newline and the sequence ID from the hold space to the pattern space
    G
    # swap the two bits of the pattern space around, deleting the newline
    s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2 \1/
}
```

Testing it:

```
$ sed -f script.sed file
ID_1 ACGTGTAGCGGTTCAGACG
ID_1 ACCATGCATGATCCATCCAGG
ID_1 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_1 ATGCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCC
ID_2 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_2 GCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCCATT
```

Without a separate script file:

```
$ sed -e '/^=/d' -e '/^SEQUENCE_ID=/{s///;h;d;}' -e '/^PRIMER.*=/{s///;G;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2 \1/;}' file
ID_1 ACGTGTAGCGGTTCAGACG
ID_1 ACCATGCATGATCCATCCAGG
ID_1 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_1 ATGCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCC
ID_2 CACAGCCACAGCAGCACAC
ID_2 GCAGGTGATCAAGTTACGCCATT
```

Shorter variant:

```
$ sed -n -e '/^SEQUENCE_ID=/{s///;h;}' -e '/^PRIMER.*=/{s///;G;s/^\(.*\)\n\(.*\)$/\2 \1/p;}' file
```